# Transcribir programa a Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

Verán encontré este código que me es de mucha utilidad pero esta escrito en python 2.6 y necesito pasarlo a python 3.6 . alguien podria ayudarme.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scikits.audiolab as audiola **#Este modulo solo esta para python 2.6**
sound = audiolab.sndfile('Violin_for_spectrogram.ogg', 'read')
y = sound.read_frames(sound.get_nframes())
Pxx, freqs, bins, im = plt.specgram(y, NFFT=512, Fs=44100)
plt.xlim(0, len(y) / 44100.0)
plt.ylim(0, 22050.0)
plt.colorbar(im).set_label(u'Intensidad (dB)')
plt.xlabel(u'Tiempo (s)')
plt.ylabel(u'Frecuencia (Hz)')
```

Comment: cual es el problema que se te presenta al ejecutarlo así?

Comment: Te recomiendo que veas la documentación de Python 3. En este caso [la versión 3.6.5rc1](https://docs.python.org/3/) que es la más estable por el momento. No creo que hayan cambiado muchas cosas. Por otro lado veo que se ha agregado algunos módulos, en especial uno llamado [audiolab](http://cournape.github.io/audiolab/) que es solo para python 2.6, te recomiendo busques otra alternativa al módul o alguna actualización del mismo.

Comment: @Diesan Romero.  ya busque otras soluciones pero no hay otro con las funciones de audiolan en python 3. Lo necesito para generar un espectrograma de audio, conoceras alguna manera de realizarlo en python 3

Comment: Siento no poder ayudarte con eso, no conozco que es un espectrograma de audio. Buscaré, y te comentaré si es posible. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu código es compatible con python 3 sin cambios, excepto por que hace uso de la biblioteca `audiolab`, que sólo funciona con python 2, y que por tanto no podrá ser utilizada y debes reemplazar por otra que te dé la misma funcionalidad.

Dices que necesitas esa biblioteca para hacer un espectrograma de audio, pero no es así. Quien está creando el espectrograma en tu código es `matplotlib.pyplot.specgram()`, la cual es perfectamente compatible con python 3.6.

Para lo único para lo que tu código  usa `audiolab` es para cargar el archivo de audio en formato `.ogg`. Esto mismo puedes hacerlo con el módulo `pysoundfile`.

Por tanto:

1. Instala en tu linux los binarios de la biblioteca `libsndfile1` (pues `pysoundfile` no es más que un *wrapper* alrededor de esa bibioteca):

   ```
   $ sudo apt install libsndfile1
   ```
2. Instala el módulo python (mejor si lo estás haciendo todo dentro de un *virtualenv*, pero eso no muestro aquí cómo se haría).

   ```
   $ pip install pysoundfile
   ```

Con esto instalado, para leer el archivo basta usar la función `soundfile.read()`, que te devuelve ya los datos en forma de array numpy y no necesitas hacer uso de `read_frames` como hacías antes. También te devuelve la frecuencia de muestreo del fichero, y así no necesitas prefijar por código su valor a 44100.0. Puedes quitar también las `u` delante de los strings porque en python3 todas las cadenas son tipo unicode por defecto.

En definitiva, tu código quedaría así:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import soundfile as sf

data, samplerate = sf.read('Violin_for_spectrogram.ogg')
# sound = audiolab.sndfile('Violin_for_spectrogram.ogg', 'read')
y = data
Pxx, freqs, bins, im = plt.specgram(y, NFFT=512, Fs=samplerate, cmap="inferno")
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(10,6)
plt.xlim(0, len(y) / samplerate)
plt.ylim(0, samplerate/2)
plt.colorbar(im).set_label('Intensidad (dB)')
plt.xlabel('Tiempo (s)')
plt.ylabel('Frecuencia (Hz)')
plt.show()
```

Y produce esta bonita figura (comparar con la que se ve [aquí](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Violin_for_spectrogram.ogg))

[image: Resultado]

Comment: ,Gracias amigo, disculpa estoy trabajando en un proyecto que involucra gratificación de audio y no se mucho del peño crees que podrías apoyarme .